# Is it possible to use an operator like function?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use operators as function callback in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692626/can-i-use-operators-as-function-callback-in-php)

Is it possible to use an operator like a function in PHP?

For example, I've written a little function that looks like this:

```
function aggregate($values,$function,$initial=null) {
    $agg = $initial === null ? array_shift($values) : $initial;
    while($values) {
        $agg = call_user_func($function,$agg,array_shift($values));
    }
    return $agg;
}
```

I'm wondering if it would be possible to call it with something like

```
 agggregate(array(1,2,3),'+');
```

Which would yield `1+2+3=6`.

If not, I guess I could call it like this:

```
 agggregate(array(1,2,3),function($a,$b){return $a+$b;});
```

But it's not as compact.

---

I just noticed this is identical to `array_reduce`; it's not necessary to point this out ;)

Comment: +1 for trying something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the anonymous function is the way to go in PHP. Unfortunately it does not have something like python's `operator` module.

Comment: Btw, there is `bcadd`. In conjunction with `array_reduce` it would do what OP wants

Comment: That function does not operate on numbers but strings. It's probably *much* slower.

Comment: anonymous functions are slow as well (in comparison to plain and obvious `for()` implementation)

Comment: Bummer. I knew it was possible in other languages, but I couldn't remember which. Thanks!

Comment: More on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692626/can-i-use-operators-as-function-callback-in-php

Comment: @JeroenOfferijns: Didn't see that one. Feel free to vote to close.

Comment: Not at all, it's similar, but not a duplicate at all ;)